# Android Supportv4 can't be packed into apk

Tags: android, adt

My Project is a Eclipse project with ADT Version 21(I know it's old). It can compile very well, but When I run the project and export a apk file, it will crash with "NoClassDefFoundError".

I decompile the apk file and the android.support.** was not packed into apk. It really confused me what happened.

I have seached a lot, it's not a " adt22 problem" and the supportv4 file is located in libs and added to export group.

If anyone want to reproduce the error, download the [example](http://sdk.umsns.com/download/android/4.3.0/?custom=240518168703) , import the social_sdk_example project into your eclipse(adt=21,windows). The problem won't happen on mac or adt23.

Comment: Convert to Gradle already. I am tired of this "help me compile my legacy app". I can help you convert to Gradle + AS. It is very simple.

Comment: Why is adt21 better than 23? Just curious.

Comment: @JaredBurrows  I'm tired of such useless reply,too, Of course I know It works On Gradle and ADT23. But we provide service for third-party developer, we can't make those people to use adt23 or gradle.

Comment: we provide service for third-party developer, we can't make those people to use adt23 or gradle。。。